# Salesforce 1 viewport issue in ios

Tags: html, salesforce, viewport, visualforce, apex

I have been creating visualforce pages for salesforce 1 mobile app for ios.
On scrolling the page the button seems not to be clicked as the viewport moves.

Can somebody suggest any thing?

thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can any one following script in your page

1. Add the following JavaScript to your page:

```
<script> 
(function(){try{var a=navigator.userAgent;if((a.indexOf('Salesforce')!=-1)&&(a.indexOf('iPhone')!=-1||a.indexOf('iPad')!=-1)&&(a.indexOf('OS/8')!=-1||a.indexOf('OS 8')!=-1)&&(a.indexOf('Safari')==-1)){ 
var s=document.createElement('style'); 
s.innerHTML="html,html body{overflow: auto;-webkit-overflow-scrolling:touch;}body{position:absolute;left:0;right:0;top:0;bottom:0;}"; 
document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(s);}}catch(e){}})(); 
</script>
```

2. Add the following JavaScript to your page:

```
<script> 
var ua=navigator.userAgent; 
if((ua.indexOf('Salesforce')!=-1)&&(ua.indexOf('iPhone')!=-1||ua.indexOf('iPad')!=-1)&&(ua.indexOf('OS/8')!=-1||ua.indexOf('OS 8')!=-1)&&(ua.indexOf('Safari')==-1)){ 
function IOS_SCROLL_BOOTSTRAP() { 
var children = Array.prototype.slice.call(document.body.children), 
placeholder = document.createElement('section'), 
fragment = document.createDocumentFragment(), 
styles, 
width, 
height; 
children.forEach(function(c){fragment.appendChild(c);}); 
placeholder.appendChild(fragment); 
styles = [ 
'width:100%;', 
'height:', (window.screen.height - 42), 'px;', 
'position: absolute; overflow: auto; -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch' 
].join(''); 
placeholder.style.cssText = styles; 
document.body.appendChild(placeholder); 
} 
window.addEventListener('load', function (e) { 
IOS_SCROLL_BOOTSTRAP(); 
}); 
} 
</script>
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please keep in mind that you will be more likely to attract upvotes for your helpful answers if they are easy to read. The way this code is indented and formatted makes it very difficult to follow what you are doing. Please read the [Markdown Editing Help](http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help) page if you are unclear on how to format your post.